# Handle COM library Crash inside C# library

Tags: c#, .net, com, interop, iis-8

I am calling a C library method in my .NET library as below .

```
[DllImport(@"abc.dll",CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern unsafe int DoSomething(
```

Calling above method using `DoSomething()`

Both of these gets loaded into to w3wp since they are part of the web project. Due to some exception inside C library, whole worker process is getting crashed.

Is there anyway to handle this inside the C# class where I call C method?

Comment: have you tried exception handling when calling the method?

Comment: Yes, There is exception block around the call. But its not going there...

Comment: This is not a COM method, just a plain C function exported from a native DLL.  Knowing exactly how it crashes is pretty important, but no matter what you do you'll have to be able to actually fix that code.  Use a telephone to talk to the author of this code.  Be sure to have a minimum repro available, better than what you did here, or he'll ignore you.